# Removing unneeded values from a file

Tags: duplicates

I have this problem in which I have to remove some data from a file 
For example:
if the file is like given below:

```
0 7 9
0 7 2 
0 8 1
1 2 6
1 2 8
```

I need to filter the values and get the desired result as

```
0 8 1 
1 2 6
0 7 2
```

that is no duplicates in first and second column and minimum value in the third column.

Actually i have tried a lot of threads in this website and other but i am unable to right a comparison function for this.

```
#include<Myheader.txt>

using namespace std;

ifstream vin("input.txt");
ofstream fout("out.txt");

struct point
{
    double x,t,r;
};


vector<point> temp;
vector<point> temp2;


void main()
{
int i=0;
double x1,y1,z1;
while(!vin.eof())
{
vin>>x1>>y1>>z1;
point hold;
hold.x=x1;hold.t=y1;hold.r=z1;
temp.push_back(hold);
}
for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++)
{
point holde;
holde.x=temp[i].x;
holde.t=temp[i].t;
holde.r=temp[i].r;
for(int ii=0;ii<temp.size();ii++)
{
if(holde.x==temp[ii].x)
{
if(holde.t==temp[ii].t)
{
if(holde.r<temp[ii].r)
{
temp2.push_back(holde);
}
}
}
}
}
for(int jj=0; jj<temp2.size();jj++)
{
fout<<temp2[jj].x<<"\t"<<temp2[jj].t<<"\t"<<temp2[jj].r<<endl;
}
cout<<"end";
_getch();
}
```

Comment: It may help people if you explain your problem, what you have tried and what problems exist.

Comment: sir, actually i was just doing it with if else statements. i am a newbie. just suggest me a way i will do it. please

Comment: suggest me reading something on this topic. Please help

Comment: Thanks for uploading some code. I will check it out now. Answered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Comment: ok.yes i am learning the formatting and other etiquette

Comment: @kyle please see the code and help me

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I would do this with multi dimensional arrays. I do not know what language you are using to program it but if you read each line and put each character into a 2 dimensional array, you could easily do some comparisons from there. If you provide a language I can provide some better links to get you started.

Reading a file: [Link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y52yxde8.aspx&ei=hcXPUcP9NLa-4AOE3YHoCQ&usg=AFQjCNErXoiyNgMHLregsGTvZf-K6RYa8Q&sig2=_g5w3Meguz4MTwwlrMWF_A&bvm=bv.48572450,d.dmg)

You make have to make substrings though. Do you know how to use multi dimensional arrays?
If not, check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/42045/) out

Comment: Yes i know how to use a 2d array but not able to write the logic of comparison

Comment: okay well you could use something like this for checking for duplicates in the column. if(array[0][j] == array[1][j] || etc)